# How to handle NHibernate Session has already been garbage collected exception

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

We have an asp.net MVC web application and we are using NHibernate as an ORM with the implementation of the repository pattern. We have a factory of the NHibernate session, there is a long-running thread which uses session from there, sometimes from this thread we got an exception while using NHibernate query.

**Session has already been garbage collected**

The exception came from NHibernate weak reference management, here is a screenshot from the code base of nhibernate https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/DefaultQueryProvider.cs

So how can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: You create again that session....

Comment: Seems like an issue in your application. Most likely your LINQ query is executed outside of session scope.